# PyQt, click action on Qwidget

Tags: python, qt4, click, pyqt

I have this simple problem, I can grab the event of a click on button, but now I need to handle a click over a widget, here is part of the code:

```
self.widget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
self.widget.setStyleSheet("QWidget { background-color: %s }" % color.name())
self.widget.setGeometry(150, 22, 50, 50)
self.connect(???)  <-- here
```

What should I put in the "???" to grab a click action over the created widget?

Answer (score 24):

you can try this
i found this from [this blog site's comment box from Jared Glass](http://popdevelop.com/2010/05/an-example-on-how-to-make-qlabel-clickable/) It was working fine for me

```
self.widget.mouseReleaseEvent=self.myfunction
```

or

```
self.widget.mouseReleaseEvent=lambda event:print 'working'
```

or

```
self.widget.mouseReleaseEvent=lambda event,my_variable:self.myfunction(event,my_variable)
```

only the last example is what i have written on my own rest all have been mentioned in http://popdevelop.com/2010/05/an-example-on-how-to-make-qlabel-clickable/ .
The last code helps you to pass any variables eg:widget name or widget number if multiple widgets exists.

Comment: This is awesome! Works like a dream.

Comment: @Ja8zyjits

The last one does not seem to work for me. I think the `mouseReleaseEvent` by default just passes the event. Do you think I will have to override the widget's `mouseReleaseEvent` to pass the extra argument? 
In its current form it says 
`TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'my_variable' `

Comment: @Tanvir, I believe we are assigning a new definition to the `mouseReleaseEvent` here, and we are passing the required variables. This is done while registering the event.

Comment: @Ja8zyjits is there another way to send a var?

Answer (score 8):

Use mousePressEvent instead.

```
import sys

from PyQt4.QtGui import QWidget, QApplication

class MyWidget(QWidget):
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print "clicked"

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

widget = MyWidget()
widget.show()

app.exec_()
```