# Can't Connect PySide QSvgWidget with clicked event

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, pyside2

I'm building a Popup Window with PySide2.

I'd like to print some text when clicking on an `QSvgWidget`.

But this seems to not be supported?

I get error message:

```
AttributeError: 'PySide2.QtSvg.QSvgWidget' object has no attribute 'clicked'
```

Reading the [QSvgWidget docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsvgwidget.html#details), I don't see anything that says that 'clicked' is not supported. Am I missing something here? Is there a reasonable work around?

```py
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
from PySide2 import QtCore
from PySide2 import QtGui, QtSvg 

logo = """<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 56 24"><path d="M20.9 19.3h-2.12v-1.24c-.8.94-1.5 1.4-2.23 1.4-.66 0-1.1-.3-1.34-.87-.12-.35-.22-.88-.22-1.67V7.9h2.12V17.16c.05.3.18.42.45.42.4 0 .78-.37 1.23-1V7.9h2.12v11.4M13.4 11.62c0-1.22-.23-2.13-.66-2.7-.56-.8-1.45-1.1-2.35-1.1-1.02 0-1.8.3-2.35 1.1-.44.57-.67 1.5-.67 2.7v4.07c0 1.2.2 2.04.64 2.6.56.8 1.48 1.2 2.37 1.2.9 0 1.82-.4 2.4-1.2.4-.56.6-1.4.6-2.6V11.6zm-2.1 4.3c.1 1.13-.25 1.7-.9 1.7-.66 0-1-.57-.9-1.7V11.4c-.1-1.13.24-1.66.9-1.66.65 0 1 .53.9 1.66v4.52zM5.03 13.1v6.2H2.8v-6.2S.47 5.46 0 4.04h2.35L3.92 10l1.56-5.95h2.34l-2.8 9.04" fill="#111111"/><path d="M42.74 9.7c-.33 0-.7.2-1.05.52v6.86c.33.34.7.5 1.04.5.6 0 .85-.42.85-1.55v-4.86c0-1.13-.27-1.46-.86-1.46M51.08 11.07c0-1.05-.27-1.36-.94-1.36-.67 0-.96.3-.96 1.35v1.25h1.9v-1.23" fill="#e62117"/><path d="M55.67 5.28s-.33-2.3-1.33-3.33C53.07.6 51.64.6 51 .53 46.33.2 39.32.2 39.32.2h-.02s-7 0-11.67.33c-.65.08-2.08.08-3.35 1.42-1 1.02-1.32 3.33-1.32 3.33s-.34 2.72-.34 5.44v2.55c0 2.72.34 5.43.34 5.43s.32 2.32 1.32 3.34c1.27 1.34 2.94 1.3 3.68 1.43 2.67.26 11.35.34 11.35.34s7.03 0 11.7-.34c.65-.08 2.07-.08 3.34-1.42 1-1.02 1.33-3.34 1.33-3.34S56 16 56 13.27v-2.55c0-2.72-.33-5.44-.33-5.44zM29.95 19.3h-2.23v-13h-2.35V4.18h7.04V6.3h-2.45v13zm8.05 0h-2.12v-1.24c-.8.94-1.5 1.4-2.23 1.4-.66 0-1.1-.3-1.34-.87-.12-.35-.22-.88-.22-1.67V8h2.12v9.17c.05.3.18.42.45.42.4 0 .78-.37 1.23-1V8H38v11.3zm7.7-3.38c0 1.04-.07 1.78-.2 2.26-.28.84-.87 1.27-1.67 1.27-.72 0-1.46-.44-2.14-1.28v1.14h-2.02V4.18h2V9.1c.66-.8 1.4-1.27 2.15-1.27.8 0 1.34.47 1.6 1.3.15.47.28 1.2.28 2.27v4.52zm4.46 1.67c.5 0 .8-.28.9-.83.02-.1.02-.6.02-1.42h2.12v.32c0 .66-.05 1.13-.07 1.33-.07.46-.23.87-.47 1.23-.56.82-1.4 1.22-2.45 1.22-1.05 0-1.85-.38-2.44-1.16-.43-.57-.7-1.4-.7-2.6v-3.96c0-1.2.25-2.14.68-2.72.58-.77 1.4-1.18 2.42-1.18s1.82.4 2.4 1.18c.4.58.65 1.46.65 2.67V14H49.2v2.02c0 1.05.3 1.57.98 1.57z" fill="#e62117"/></svg>"""

def printHello():
    print("hello")

class MyPopup(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyPopup, self).__init__(
            #popup is being created for houdini, thus the hou module
            hou.qt.mainWindow(),
        )
        self.configure_dialog()
        self.widgets()
        self.layouts()
        self.connections()
        
    def configure_dialog(self)->None:
        self.setMinimumWidth(100)
        self.setMinimumHeight(100)
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() |  QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | QtCore.Qt.Popup )
    
    def connections(self)->None:
        self.icon.clicked.connect(printHello)
    
    def layouts(self)->None:
        self.barLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self)
        self.barLayout.addWidget(self.icon)

    def widgets(self)->None:
        svg_bytes = bytearray(logo, encoding='utf-8')
        defaultSize = QtSvg.QSvgRenderer(svg_bytes).defaultSize()
        svgWidget = QtSvg.QSvgWidget()
        svgWidget.renderer().load(svg_bytes)
        svgWidget.setGeometry(100,100,300,300)
        svgWidget.setFixedSize(defaultSize)
        self.icon = svgWidget
            
popup = MyPopup()
popup.show()
```

Comment: "Reading the QSvgWidget docs, I don't see anything that says normal user interactions are not supported." Do you see any reference about a `clicked` signal?

Answer (score 0):

It looks liked the `clicked` event is not supported for all widget types. Seems to work for buttons and text inputs.

Instead for the icon I used `mouseReleaseEvent`:

```py
self.icon.mouseReleaseEvent = lambda event:self.printHello()
```

See: [PyQt, click action on Qwidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996511/pyqt-click-action-on-qwidget)

Comment: First of all, `clicked` is not an *event*: at most, it's a *signal*. The `clicked` "name" exists for some widgets, but it has different purposes and argument signatures. Then, doing the above *might* work for very basic cases, but it's also a discouraged practice. If you want to properly handle mouse events, subclass QSvgWidget, emit the signal whenever appropriate, and/or call the base implementation.